# How to read key input from stdin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm trying to build a program in Kotlin native. The target is Windows in my case : mingwX64("mingw"). I want to build just a simple exe file without any dependencies.

How can I have a loop that just reads characters as they are entered by key presses from stdin?

I know that there's the "readLine()" function, but I would like to read individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read individual keypress (in non-portable way) use [Get key press in windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212646/get-key-press-in-windows-console), all APIs there shall be available via `platform.windows` package.