# How to make my program appear and disappear on the screen

Tags: c++, winapi

My program simulates some mouse movements, but the cmd screen remains open, I would like to put a key to appear and disappear from the screen, and another key for it to close completely

Comment: Is it for windows? Add tag if it is. There are no platform independent solutions for that.

Comment: So, you're trying to control a PC without it looking like you're controlling the PC? Not cool.

Answer (score 1):

If "cmd screen" is meant as Windows console then there are simple Windows API calls:

```
// this hides console window
::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

// this shows
::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOW);

// this checks visibility
if (::IsWindowVisible(::GetConsoleWindow())) {
    // do your things
}
```

You need to include windows.h for those. As you wrote that you alter mouse you have likely done it already.

Comment: tnks, I'm not able to put a key, it's giving some errors that I don't know, can you put it to appear and disappear on the INSERT key?

Comment: That is more complicated. Answer to that question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212646/get-key-press-in-windows-console  You should ask every question as separate, that helps next people to search answers.